# How to append two data in url that has to be passed in jquery

Tags: jquery, url

I am trying to append two ids in url but this code is saying 0

```
   var url = 'post_comment.php?userid=' + $('.post_comment').data('userid') & 'postid='+postid;
```

when i try

```
   var url = 'post_comment.php?userid=' + $('.post_comment').data('userid');
```

it works. How should i add another id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

```
var url = 'post_comment.php?userid=' + $('.post_comment').data('userid') + '&postid='+postid;
```

To join the two string or string with variable javascript uses "+" operator.

Answer (score 0):

Check the ampersand in your code in the first line and replace it with a "+".

```
var url = 'post_comment.php?userid=' + $('.post_comment').data('userid') & 'postid='+postid;
```

Should be

```
var url = 'post_comment.php?userid=' + $('.post_comment').data('userid') + 'postid='+postid;
```

Remember that & is the bitwise AND, and will yield 0 for a & b if a is not an integer or b is not a numeric string or an integer. Also it doesn't look that you actually wanted to put the & operator, so replacing it with + (plus) will be enough.